# PHP Invalid parameter number:

Tags: php, mysql

> **PHP Error**: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens.

What am i missing here? I'm trying to add a new user for my med application.

```
public function register($uname,$umail,$upass,$fname,$llastname)
{
    try
    {
        $new_password = password_hash($upass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users(name, lastname, user_name, user_email, user_pass) VALUES(:fname, :llastname, :uname, :umail, :upass)");
        $stmt->bindparam(":fname", $fname);
        $stmt->bindparam(":llastname", $llastname);
        $stmt->bindparam(":uname", $uname);
        $stmt->bindparam(":umail", $umail);
        $stmt->bindparam(":upass", $new_password);                                        

        $stmt->execute();   

        return $stmt;   
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }               
}


public function doLogin($uname,$umail,$upass)
{
    try
    {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT name, lastname, user_id, user_name, user_email, user_pass FROM users WHERE name=:fname, lastname=:llastname, user_name=:uname OR user_email=:umail ");
        $stmt->execute(array(':uname'=>$uname, ':umail'=>$umail));
        $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if($stmt->rowCount() == 1)
        {
            if(password_verify($upass, $userRow['user_pass']))
            {
                $_SESSION['user_session'] = $userRow['user_id'];
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        //HTTPS 
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

addUser.php did i bind it correctly ?

```
$uname = strip_tags($_POST['txt_uname']);
$umail = strip_tags($_POST['txt_umail']);
$upass = strip_tags($_POST['txt_upass']);   
$fname = strip_tags($_POST['txt_fname']);
$llastname = strip_tags($_POST['txt_llastname']);
```

Comment: invalid syntax for SELECT. see the manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
$stmt = $user->runQuery("SELECT name, lastname, user_name,user_email 
                         FROM users 
                         WHERE name=:fname, 
                               lastname=:llastname,
                               user_name=:uname 
                               OR user_email=:umail");
```

You use 4 (four!) parameters: `:fname`, `:llastname`, `:uname`, `:umail`

Then, while executing it you ONLY bind 2 (two) parameters:

```
$stmt->execute(array(':uname' => $uname, ':umail' => $umail));
```

This is exactly why you're getting that error.

Any by the way, your SQL query is errored. Instead of `,` (comma) you should use `AND` to join the `WHERE` conditions. Like this:

```
$stmt = $user->runQuery("SELECT name, lastname, user_name,user_email 
                     FROM users 
                     WHERE name=:fname 
                       AND lastname=:llastname
                       AND user_name=:uname 
                        OR user_email=:umail");
```

Although, I am not entirely sure about ANDs and ORs there, you may need to use parantheses to achieve the logic you need

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ' lastname='lkqjwekljqwe', ' at line 3

having new error. is it a syntax error?

Comment: Yes it tells you "you can't use commas in WHERE", you should use ANDs and ORs instead. Look, I've just updated the answer